# Beamer: how to move whole "frame content" a bit left?

Tags: beamer, vspace

I am pretty new to beamer, and I am trying to move the whole "frame content" a bit left, for example, -1em. I am trying to use `\vspace{-1em}`, but it doesn't work, however, `\hspace{-1em}` does work, which can move whole frame content up.

Here is an minimal example:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{frame title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First
    \begin{itemize}
    \item First.1
    \item First.1
    \end{itemize}
  \item second
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and here is what I want to do:
[image]

BTW, I would not like to use any other themes, just the original one. Please kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract from `beamer` user guide (p.76, section 8.3 *"Frame and Margin Sizes"*, v3.67):

> You can change the size of the left and right margins, which default
> to 1 cm.
>
> `\setbeamersize{⟨options⟩}` The following ⟨options⟩ can be
> given:
>
> - `text margin left=⟨TEX dimension⟩` sets a new left margin. This excludes the left sidebar. Thus, it is the distance between the right
>   edge of the left sidebar and the left edge of the text.
> - `text margin right=⟨TEX dimension⟩` sets a new right margin.

Example:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\setbeamersize{
  text margin left=3mm,
  text margin right=3mm,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{frame title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First
    \begin{itemize}
    \item First.1
    \item First.1
    \end{itemize}
  \item second
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That really helps!